# ¿Es posible bloquear la ventana principal con un dialoghost del nuget materialdesign?

Tags: wpf, vb

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Visual Basic WPF y estoy utilizando los Nugets MaterialDesignThemes y MaterialDesignColors. En vez de utilizar el MessageBox y conseguir un aspecto mejorado y acorde al Nuget de material design, estoy utilizando la opción DialogHost. He conseguido que se abra el dialogo, pero no se me abre en modo modal, esto es, el dialogo no bloquea la ventana principal y permite editar textboxes, pulsar botones de esta ventana principal.
¿Existe alguna propiedad o función que permita que el dialogo deshabilite la edición de la ventana principal?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al español. Revisa el apartado [answer] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta. También puedes hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que deduzco no has creado tu DialogHost a nivel de la ventana principal, bastaría con tener solo este único DialogHost, y llamarlo cuando lo necesites desde donde estés

en tu venta principal:

```
<Window x:Class="TuVentanaPrincipal.View"
......>

   <materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog">
       //aquí tu codigo
   </materialDesign:DialogHost>
</Window>
```

y de donde quieras hacer la llamada puedes en el código xaml el command:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
```

o por code behind o ViewModel usando la propiedad:

```
 DialogHost.Show
```

para ello te sugiero leer la documentación
en: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs

con ello obtendras algo similar a:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como ves el DialogHost cubre toda la pantalla de la aplicación impidiendo la interacción con los demás controles, la clave esta en crear el DialogHost en la ventana principal y llamarlo desde quieras hacer la llamada ya sea en otra pagina